# Verify my understanding in this code. Check errors

Tags: java, exception, io

I have this code:

```
   /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package askisi5;

import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Alexandros
 */

public class IO_Tester {

    public static int readInt() {
        byte b[] = new byte[16];
        String str;


        System.in.read(b);
        str = (new String(b)).trim();
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }
}
```

As far as understand this code we create a function named readInt() that returns an integer. Inside this function we create a byte array of 16 elements nad then we declare a String variable str.

The next lines are a bit unclear to me

System.in.read(b); --> Do we input data to program from array b?

str = (new String(b)).trim(); --> It seems that we trim leading and trailing whitespace from String b. b is converted to a String. We save result to str

return Integer.parseInt(str); --> We return the integer after we have done a type conversion?

Why when I compile this piece of code it gives an error?
error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown;
        System.in.read(b);

thanks

Comment: `System.in.read(b);` reads data from Standard input stream to `b`. That's it. The rest is correct.

Comment: Why when I compile the code it throws an exception?

Comment: @Hackerdashi it isn't correct. You need to check the number of bytes read from `System.in` (returned by `read`), and use that to limit the number of bytes used to construct the string via the [`offset` and `length` constructor parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-byte:A-int-int-).

Comment: @AndyTurner I didn't say whether the program was correct or not, I verified his understanding of the program (as he wanted).

Comment: @Alexandros81 what is the specific exception thrown (please edit question to include stack trace). Also, please give your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote the java doc for the methods. Java is a beautiful language with almost all the APIs (at least from the core language) being very well documented.

```
 System.in.read(b);
```

> Reads some number of bytes from the input stream and stores them into
>   the buffer array b. The number of bytes actually read is returned as
>   an integer. This method blocks until input data is available, end of
>   file is detected, or an exception is thrown.
>
> If the length of b is zero, then no bytes are read and 0 is returned;
>   otherwise, there is an attempt to read at least one byte. If no byte
>   is available because the stream is at the end of the file, the value
>   -1 is returned; otherwise, at least one byte is read and stored into b.
>
> The first byte read is stored into element b[0], the next one into
>   b[1], and so on. The number of bytes read is, at most, equal to the
>   length of b. Let k be the number of bytes actually read; these bytes
>   will be stored in elements b[0] through b[k-1], leaving elements b[k]
>   through b[b.length-1] unaffected.
>
> The read(b) method for class InputStream has the same effect as:
>   read(b, 0, b.length)  Parameters:b the buffer into which the data is
>   read.Returns:the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if
>   there is no more data because the end of the stream has been
>   reached.Throws:IOException - If the first byte cannot be read for any
>   reason other than the end of the file, if the input stream has been
>   closed, or if some other I/O error occurs.NullPointerException - if b
>   is null.

Next is the `trim()` called on the object of String. [`new String(b)` simply creates a new String object by decoding the specified array of bytes using the platform's default charset ]

> A string whose value is this string, with any leading and trailing white space removed, or this string if it has no leading or trailing white space.

Next is `Integer.parseInt(str)` For this read below.

> the integer value represented by the argument in decimal.